# get 2 lists of unique and duplicate elements of a parent list

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a list:mylist=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8]:

I want to get 2 list of unique and duplicate elements:
duplicate element's list:[1,4,5,6]
unique element's list:[2,3,7,8]

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You are more likely to get answers for your question if you include the attempts you have made so far. This helps us to know the level of Python for a good answer and assures us that you are not just fishing for us to do your homework for you. Have you looked at Python's `set` or `counter` classes?

Comment: Create your 2 output lists.  Step through your input list.  Check if the item is in your unique list. If not, add to unique list.  If it is, check if it's in your duplicate list.  If it isn't add it.  Pretty simple

Comment: @Rory Daulton: I have looked for set(), I tried new_list=list(set(mylist)), which gave me distinct numbers in list. Now I want to get the list element's count. I tried using mylist.count(), but could not get through it.i don't want to use counter right now

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(mylist)
l1 = []
l2 = []
for key in counts:
    if counts[key] > 1:
        l1.append(key)
    else:
        l2.append(key)
```

This will give you two lists: `l1` and `l2` which contain duplicated and unique elements, respectively.

Comment: you can use `list(set(mylist))` instead of `Counter(mylist)`

Comment: `list(set(mylist))` will return a list with one occurrence of each element that appears in the original list. that was my original thought as well but not what OP is looking for

Comment: I will post my almost same with yours

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same with [@JasonStein's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44768037/584676), just provide base function `list(set(mylist))`:

```
mylist=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8]
L1=[]
L2=[]
for i in list(set(mylist)):
    if mylist.count(i)>1:
        L1.append(i)
    else:
        L2.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this way:

```
mylist=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,8]
#case your list is not ordened:
mylist.sort()
duplicated=[]
unique=[]
for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
  if i<len(mylist):
    #comparing the value with the next or the previous in the list:
    if (mylist[i]==mylist[i+1]) or (mylist[i]==mylist[i-1]):
      #if duplicated, add to it's list
      duplicated.append(mylist[i])
    else:
      #if unique, add to it's list
      unique.append(mylist[i])
print("Duplicated: ",list(set(duplicated)))
print("Unique: ",list(set(unique)))
```

Hope had help you.

Comment: this only works if the duplicates are adjacent, which is not always the case

Comment: @JasonStein In this case, you just insert a `mylist.sort()` before the `for` statement.